# How do I convert a string in seconds to time in C++

Tags: c++, time

I have a string that stores the no of seconds since a process started. I need to convert this string with the no of seconds to time in C++. I need to subtract this time from the current time to get the time that this process started. I am confused and I do not know how to go about it. Please could someone help me out. I am a bit new to C++

Comment: `std::stoi` will convert your string to an integer. You can then do whatever you want with the integer. Subtract it from some clock time, etc.. `std::stof` is the float version.

Comment: I'm sure you can convert it a _lot_ quicker than that.

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds::rep` is `long long` so I think `std::stoll` would be best here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use standard `<time.h>` routines (`time`, and `gmtime` or `localtime`).**

For example:

```
void PrintProcessStartTimeAndDate(int numOfSeconds)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* ptm;
    time(&rawtime);
    rawtime -= numOfSeconds;
    ptm = gmtime(&rawtime); // or localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("Process started at %.2d:%.2d:%.2d on %.2d/%.2d/%.2d\n",
            ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec,ptm->tm_mday,ptm->tm_mon+1,ptm->tm_year+1900);
}
```

Please note that `gmtime` and `localtime` routines are **not thread-safe**.

This fact is due to the pointer-to-static-structure that each one of them returns.

Comment: c, not c++, and very prone to err

Comment: So this will not work in C++ because it works in C??? Also, can you please elaborate on the 'prone to error' issue?

Comment: the question asks about and is tagged with c++, so, c++ style, and not c style, is expected, even though c++ accepts a subset of c. It's error prone, in the sense of using big non checked printf formatting, maintaining this kind of code in a codebase, adding changes, etc, is unsafe.

Comment: Calling `printf` is prone to runtime errors in general. That's the nature of this function, which I agree on. What I don't understand is, what that has to do with this specific answer, as you could basically infer the same analysis on any given piece of code that uses `printf`. And in any case, I only added it in order to give an example on the use of `struct tm`. The only flaw I see in this answer is the fact that `gmtime` and `localtime` are not thread-safe, due to the pointer-to-static-structure that they return.

Comment: And last but not least, here is a link to the C++ reference of the time routines that I've used: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/.

Comment: @barakmanos cplusplus.com is inaccurate. Please use [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) instead.

Comment: the issue for me is that, an answer on SO is a public advice on programming, and, since the OP is asking about C++, why include what's generally viewed as a bad practice (without notice) in the answer? It's potentially misleading for newcomers and, kind offtopic given what the OP asks for.

Comment: generally, answering on SO, I try to cut out bad smells.

Comment: @pepper_chico, OK. First of all thank you for the two informative comments above (and sorry for the "bad smell" if any sensed). Second, reading the question, I figured OP was looking for a technical solution, hence I provided one. If the answer is flawed, then I'm always happy to get down-voted with an explanation. But in this case, it appears that the only issue you're pointing out is the use of `printf`, which is merely there to help OP test the code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try out Boost Time Library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html) or `std::chrono` if you're using newer compiler (as suggested below) and wish to stay within STL.

Comment: Or `std::chrono` depending on the user's needs.

Comment: Agreed. I missed it since I'm still working with older compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `boost.timer` and not `boost.chrono`?

Comment: Well, it could be done with `chrono`, but `boost.timer` is designed for time measurements such as prompted in the question, and is straightforward to use. As @CantChooseUsernames suggested, it depends on the user's needs, but with such a convenient tool as `boost.timer`, I wouldn't take `chrono` as my first choice in most of circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that could work:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std::chrono;

std::string elapsed_time_in_s = "123456";
system_clock::time_point then = system_clock::now() - 
    std::chrono::seconds(std::stoll(elapsed_time_in_s));

time_t then_as_time_t = system_clock::to_time_t(then);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
///
std::stringstream strs(seconds_string);
unsigned int tempTime=0;
if(!(strs >> tempTime))
    //error
//calculate around with tempTime
if(!(strs << tempTime)
    //error
if(!(strs >> seconds_string)
    //error
//new string with the current time
```